# SMSC9514 is not detected on Beagleboard xm rev C

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, beagleboard

I am using linux kernel 3.2.0. The Ethernet works fine in uboot but once the control is transfered to kernel, I see 3 ports found in the boot logs but no log for finding 5 ports hub. The log is at the end of the post.

I came accross some posts and tried to verify if proper voltage is being given to the LAN9514 chip. I tested that with following commands

2cget -f -y 1 0x4b 0x76

to get VAUX2_DEV_GRP, and 
i2cget -f -y 1 0x4b 0x79

to get VAUX2_DEDICATED, and
i2cget -f -y 1 0x4A 0xEE

to get LEDEN.
I get 0x2e and 0x05 for first two and the third value is 0x22 (0x11 should be the ideal value to turn on 3.3V for SMSC).
Now Ethernet works fine when I use a prebuilt image for kernel 2.6.32. This means the hardware is fine as it works here and in U-boot. Can anyone help me in finding out where exactly to change the LEDEN value in linux kernel.

```
[    1.548950] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
[    1.555664] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    1.562774] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.569641] usbcore: registered new interface driver net1080
[    1.576446] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
[    1.583312] usbcore: registered new interface driver zaurus
[    1.589355] cdc_ncm: 04-Aug-2011
[    1.593475] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    1.601440] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    3.622985] ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: OMAP-EHCI Host Controller
[    3.634338] ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    3.642913] ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: irq 77, io mem 0x48064800
[    3.662139] ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    3.669616] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    3.676879] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.684539] usb usb1: Product: OMAP-EHCI Host Controller
[    3.690185] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.14 ehci_hcd
[    3.695922] usb usb1: SerialNumber: ehci-omap.0
[    3.706024] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.710296] hub 1-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    3.749328] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[    3.755340] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    3.761291] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    3.767761] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    3.774169] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    3.781097] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbtest
[    3.787200] udc: OMAP UDC driver, version: 4 October 2004 (iso) (dma)
[    3.798095] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    3.812774] input: twl4030_pwrbutton as /devices/platform/omap/omap_i2c.1/i2c-1/1-0049/twl4030_pwrbutton/input/input0
[    3.828491] twl_rtc twl_rtc: Power up reset detected.
[    3.834350] twl_rtc twl_rtc: Enabling TWL-RTC.
[    3.843109] twl_rtc twl_rtc: rtc core: registered twl_rtc as rtc0
[    3.851593] i2c /dev entries driver
[    3.859161] Driver for 1-wire Dallas network protocol.
[    3.868804] OMAP Watchdog Timer Rev 0x31: initial timeout 60 sec
[    3.876678] twl4030_wdt twl4030_wdt: Failed to register misc device
[    3.883575] twl4030_wdt: probe of twl4030_wdt failed with error -16
[    4.231964] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    4.237976] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    4.242065] oprofile: hardware counters not available
[    4.247406] oprofile: using timer interrupt.
[    4.252655] TCP cubic registered
[    4.256134] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    4.260772] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    4.265655] NET: Registered protocol family 15
[    4.270690] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    4.276397] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3
[    4.284606] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    4.341247] clock: disabling unused clocks to save power
[    4.352722] regulator_init_complete: VDVI: incomplete constraints, leaving on
[    4.360687] regulator_init_complete: VDAC: incomplete constraints, leaving on
[    4.372009] input: gpio-keys as /devices/platform/gpio-keys/input/input1
[    4.382965] twl_rtc twl_rtc: setting system clock to 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (946684800)
[    4.394348] Waiting 2sec before mounting root device...
[    4.509857] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch. assuming write-enable.
[    4.521118] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 1234
[    4.531066] mmcblk0: mmc0:1234 SA04G 3.63 GiB
[    4.543792]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3
[    6.416442] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[    6.434844] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p3): using internal journal
[    6.441009] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[    6.448852] VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) on device 179:3.
[    6.455871] Freeing init memory: 316K
INIT: version 2.86 booting
Please wait: booting..
```

Comment: I suggest you try Robert C Nelson resources through http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBoard. When I build from his source, my BBxM has always worked. Sometimes in mainline that is not the case.

Comment: Hi Joe Thanks for the suggestion, I tried and it worked. There are many patches in this so just trying to understand what actually prevented 3v3 suply from Hub to LAN9514.

Comment: Hi! Did you ever find what is the specific change that fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The early revisions of the XM required the nEN_USB_PWR line to be active high. The rev C reverted to active low, which is the same as the earlier A/B/C revisions.

You can see the patch that updated this behaviour in mainline here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/5fe8b4c19dc24e3bb873daf9e96a2439a83bbd79

Various versions of these changes have been backported to older versions of the kernel.